# How to manage shared state/store in sub apps of react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the main App and two sub-apps in my React application and I am using Redux for the state management. I have to create a separate store for each sub-app. There is also a state which will be shared state between these two sub-apps.

e.g.

```
                    APP
              isAuthenticated (this is a shared state)
                /      \
               /        \
              /          \
             /            \
    ChatApp(sub-app)      GameApp(another sub-app)
    isOnline              isPlayingGame
(separate state/store)     (separate state/store)
```

I want to manage this type of state where isAuthenticated will be a shared state between the two sub-apps, and isOnline and isPlayingGame will be a separate state in the stores of the sub-apps.

How could I manage this kind of store in my application.

Comment: Please have a look at this. I think this will help 

https://redux.js.org/recipes/isolating-redux-sub-apps

Comment: Thank @Arnab. That article says about isolating the stores, but I have a common state for all apps. In my case, I have one shared state common for all the sub-app but other states are isolated.